# Saving openGL ES drawing to a PNG image file in iOS Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, opengl-es, swift3, uiimage

I am trying to save a drawing generated on iOS using openGL ES to an PNG file using CGDataProvider and CGImage functions. I have found some code on the web in Objective-C which I converted to Swift 3. The code compiles but fails during runtime throwing an error:
**fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value** at this line:

```
let iref: CGImage = CGImage(pngDataProviderSource: provider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: CGColorRenderingIntent.defaultIntent)!
```

Code:

```
let x: Int = 0
let y: Int = 0
let dataLength: Int = Int(width) * Int(height) * 4
let pixels: UnsafeMutableRawPointer? = malloc(dataLength * MemoryLayout<GLubyte>.size)
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT.ui, 4)
glReadPixels(GLint(x), GLint(y), GLsizei(width), GLsizei(height), GLenum(GL_RGBA), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE.ui, pixels)
let pixelData: UnsafePointer = (UnsafeRawPointer(pixels)?.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self))!
let cfdata: CFData = CFDataCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, pixelData, dataLength * MemoryLayout<GLubyte>.size)

let provider: CGDataProvider! = CGDataProvider(data: cfdata)

let iref: CGImage = CGImage(pngDataProviderSource: provider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: CGColorRenderingIntent.defaultIntent)!
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: CGFloat(width), height: CGFloat(height)))
let cgcontext: CGContext? = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
cgcontext!.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.copy)
cgcontext!.draw(iref, in: CGRect(x: CGFloat(0.0), y: CGFloat(0.0), width: CGFloat(width), height: CGFloat(height)))
let image: UIImage? = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

I can't find any help on the web for Swift 3. Could you please help in fixing this error.

Comment: At least check which one is nil. You use 2 force unwraps. One with the provider and another one on the whole CGImage. Anyway try the different constructor for the provider: CGDataProvider(dataInfo: nil data:cfdata, size: size, releaseData: nil)

Comment: Its the whole CGImage becoming nil.
I tried the constructor you gave, but it fails with this error message:
Nil is not compatible with expected argument type 'CGDataProviderReleaseDataCallback' (aka '@convention(c) (Optional<UnsafeMutableRawPointer>, UnsafeRawPointer, Int) -> ()')

let provider = CGDataProvider(dataInfo: nil data:cfdata, size: size, releaseData: nil)

Comment: Ah I see now. You are using a constructor on the CGImage which expects a raw PNG data but you have raw RGBA data. The method you used expects (for instance) data from contents of file of a PNG image. You will need to use the full constructor with the raw RGBA data: CGImage(width:, height:, bitsPerComponent:, bitsPerPixel:, bytesPerRow:, space:, bitmapInfo:, provider:, decode:, shouldInterpolate:, intent:)

Comment: @Matic Oblak, Thanks a lot. This solved the issue. :)

Comment: For future reference you may want to write the resulting code in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by **Matic Oblak**, the error was gone and the code worked properly, when I replaced this line in the above code

```
let iref: CGImage = CGImage(pngDataProviderSource: provider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: CGColorRenderingIntent.defaultIntent)!
```

with this

```
let iref: CGImage? = CGImage(width: Int(width), height: Int(height), bitsPerComponent: 8, bitsPerPixel: 32, bytesPerRow: Int(width)*4, space: colorspace!, bitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Big, provider: provider, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: CGColorRenderingIntent.defaultIntent)
```

New working code:

```
let x: Int = 0
let y: Int = 0
let dataLength: Int = Int(width) * Int(height) * 4
let pixels: UnsafeMutableRawPointer? = malloc(dataLength * MemoryLayout<GLubyte>.size)
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT.ui, 4)
glReadPixels(GLint(x), GLint(y), GLsizei(width), GLsizei(height), GLenum(GL_RGBA), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE.ui, pixels)
let pixelData: UnsafePointer = (UnsafeRawPointer(pixels)?.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self))!
let cfdata: CFData = CFDataCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, pixelData, dataLength * MemoryLayout<GLubyte>.size)

let provider: CGDataProvider! = CGDataProvider(data: cfdata)

let iref: CGImage? = CGImage(width: Int(width), height: Int(height), bitsPerComponent: 8, bitsPerPixel: 32, bytesPerRow: Int(width)*4, space: colorspace!, bitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Big, provider: provider, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: CGColorRenderingIntent.defaultIntent)
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: CGFloat(width), height: CGFloat(height)))
let cgcontext: CGContext? = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
cgcontext!.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.copy)
cgcontext!.draw(iref, in: CGRect(x: CGFloat(0.0), y: CGFloat(0.0), width: CGFloat(width), height: CGFloat(height)))
let image: UIImage? = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```